# Adding description or body text to Facebook share dialog?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

After spending 5 hours on facebook share dialog for Javascript sdk, i can not find the way for adding the description('Say somthing about this')  in to the dialog.

any solution would be appreciate :)

here what I've tried:

```
   <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/products/"     data-type="button"></div>


  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with what you already have:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'your_app_id',
            version: 'v2.0',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
};

$(".fb-share-button").click(function(e){
    FB.ui({ method: "feed",
                description: "Your description",
                name: "Share this",
                link: ShareUrl,
            }, function (response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    alert("post successful");
                }
            }
    );
});
```

I hope this helps.